# How to use C# to enable a disabled wireless network card

Tags: c#, networking, wmi, adapter

I've got a problem where I need to enable a card that has been disabled already and a searcher on WMI NetworkAdapter does not return the object.

I can think of a possible way to do this but I've been unable to get it to work, thats is to create a managementObject using this as the constructor name.  but this just throws exceptions

`{\\.\root\CIMV2:Win32_NetworkAdapter.NetConnectionID='Wireless Network Connection'}`

The other way was to shell a netsh and enable the device, which is kind of ugly, or to use shell32/dll "Enable" to do the same, again, both passing just the name.  Ive been getting the name from a registry scan on `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Network` and looking for MediaType=2 to get a string list of wireless devices.  All is good if I run the application while the adapter is enabled as I can get the networkObject for the wireless device but it all falls over if the application starts while the wireless device is disabled.

Thanks

Edit : This is the code that I would love to work but no go :(

```
using System;
using System.Management;
class Sample
{
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        ManagementObject mObj = new ManagementObject("\\\\.\\root\\CIMV2:Win32_NetworkAdapter.NetConnectionID=\"Wireless Network Connection\"");
        mObj.InvokeMethod("Enable", null);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This method essentially is using C# to leverage the WMI and `Win32_NetworkAdapter` Class.  It should have methods built in for:

- Enable
- Disable

So you can execute your command on a Selected interface.

You can achieve that in this manner:

```
SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Win32_NetworkAdapter", "NetConnectionStatus=2");
ManagementObjectSearcher search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
foreach(ManagementObject result in search.Get())
{
    NetworkAdapter adapter = new NetworkAdapter(result);

    // Identify the adapter you wish to disable here. 
    // In particular, check the AdapterType and 
    // Description properties.

    // Here, we're selecting the LAN adapters.
    if (adapter.AdapterType.Equals("Ethernet 802.3")) 
    {
        adapter.Disable();
    }
}
```

There is a [blog that actually outlines such a task](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ncowburn/2008/06/24/HOWTODisableEnableNetworkConnectionsProgrammaticallyUnderVista.aspx); it defines how to create a Wrapper around the WMI Class.

Another [solution may be to also use](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.ControlService) the `ControlService` (advapi32).

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool    ControlService(IntPtr hService, SERVICE_CONTROL dwControl, ref SERVICE_STATUS lpServiceStatus);
```

Hopefully that one of those ways help..

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  What I cant seem to get it to do is Enable an adapter that is disabled as a search doesn't return anything for a disabled device.  Disabling the device is really easy but enabling a device for which you can't get the object for, is the bit that Im having trouble with.  Ideally, this is what I'm trying to get to work

Comment: Well, if you Query that exact interface it should allow you to implement in the `enable` method.  Does it not, when I try it- it works.

Comment: @Grey - do you have your wireless disabled (in device manager) before calling?  If so, what OS/.NET are you targetting?

Comment: could you please let me know the namesapce we need to include for "NetworkAdapter" class

Comment: Please, is it posible to add the namespaces that you using?

Comment: Just add `System.Management`

Comment: You need to generate the NetworkAdapter.cs class.  Open a visual studio tools command prompt. Run "mgmtclassgen Win32_NetworkAdapter -p NetworkAdapter.cs"

Answer (score 0):

```
            using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using System.ComponentModel;
            using System.Data;
            using System.Drawing;
            using System.Linq;
            using System.Text;
            using System.Windows.Forms;
            using System.Diagnostics;
            using System.Security.Principal;

            namespace WifiRouter
            {
                public partial class Form1 : Form
                {
                    bool connect = false;
                    public Form1()
                    {

                        InitializeComponent();
                    }

                    public static bool IsAdmin()
                    {
                        WindowsIdentity id = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
                        WindowsPrincipal p = new WindowsPrincipal(id);
                        return p.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
                    }
                    public void RestartElevated()
                    {
                        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                        startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
                        startInfo.FileName = System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath;
                        startInfo.Verb = "runas";
                        try
                        {
                            Process p = Process.Start(startInfo);
                        }
                        catch
                        {

                        }

                        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
                    }
                    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {
                        string ssid = textBox1.Text, key = textBox2.Text;
                        if (!connect)
                        {
                            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("SSID cannot be left blank !",
                                "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                            }
                            else
                            {

                                if (textBox2.Text == null || textBox2.Text == "")
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show("Key value cannot be left blank !",
                                    "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (key.Length >= 6)
                                    {
                                        Hotspot(ssid, key, true);
                                        textBox1.Enabled = false;
                                        textBox2.Enabled = false;
                                        button1.Text = "Stop";
                                        connect = true;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        MessageBox.Show("Key should be more then or Equal to 6 Characters !",
                                        "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Hotspot(null, null, false);
                            textBox1.Enabled = true;
                            textBox2.Enabled = true;
                            button1.Text = "Start";
                            connect = false;
                        }
                    }
                    private void Hotspot(string ssid, string key,bool status)
                    {
                        ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
                        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                        processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                        processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                        Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);

                        if (process != null)
                        {
                            if (status)
                            {
                                process.StandardInput.WriteLine("netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=" + ssid + " key=" + key);
                                process.StandardInput.WriteLine("netsh wlan start hosted network");
                                process.StandardInput.Close();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                process.StandardInput.WriteLine("netsh wlan stop hostednetwork");
                                process.StandardInput.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {
                        if (!IsAdmin())
                        {
                            RestartElevated();
                        }
                    }

                    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
                    {
                        Hotspot(null, null, false);
                        Application.Exit();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I believe,  some explanation of code would be very helpful